# Unintended zoom with PWA on iOS after device unlock

Tags: ios, zooming, progressive-web-apps

Perhaps similar to this question, although not related to rotation:
[unintended zoom on orientation change in PWA but not mobile safari iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977145/unintended-zoom-on-orientation-change-in-pwa-but-not-mobile-safari-ios)

I have an issue where if my PWA app is left running (say, on an iPad as a Kiosk) and the device sleeps / locks, upon unlocking / waking the app decides to zoom-in to a section in the middle of the page. It's not even a smooth zoom-in, it's like a badly animated 90s JPG loading checkerboard sequence as it 'switches' from one zoom level to another.

I've tried HTML meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I've tried CSS touch-action:

```
touch-action: none;
```

But nothing seems to stop it. Interestingly, with the app running in the Mobile Safari browser and not as a PWA, the issue does not occur.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Added a bounty because I need an answer to this too. I'm running a react pwa and it demonstrates something like this behaviour.

Comment: @JonaFane No, unfortunately still haven't been able to fix it :(

Comment: This Q is 4 years old and still doesn't have an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977145/unintended-zoom-on-orientation-change-in-pwa-but-not-mobile-safari-ios

Comment: @roberttolton I would like to have my PWA on iPad in kiosk mode but unable to find any good way to achieve this. Could you please let me know how can we do this? Really appreciate your help.